# Pattern for calling method which takes the most derived form of the passed object

Tags: c#

I was surprised when I ran into this situation and realized I wasn't sure what the best solution was.

Say I have the following three types:

```
class A { }
class B : A { }
class C : A { }
```

And the following three methods:

```
DoSomething(A a){ }
DoSomething(B b){ }
DoSomething(C c){ }
```

I have a `List<A>` which contains objects of type B and C

I would like to do this:

```
foreach(A a in list) { DoSomething(a) }
```

and have it call the method which matches most closely to the underlying type,
but of course this will always call `DoSomething(A a)`

I'd prefer not to have a bunch of type checking to get the right method call, and I don't want to add anything to the classes A, B or , C.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a rather well-known issue with virtual dispatch in statically typed languages: it only handles *one* parameter (`this`) "virtually"; for all other parameters, the method call is bound using the *static type* of the argument. Since your list is a list of `A`, the code is only ever going to call the `A` overload.

You would need [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) to achieve the stated goal, and since the language does not provide this out of the box unless you switch to `dynamic`, so you will have to either make the switch or implement it yourself. There are many tradeoffs to consider when making this decision (and also when deciding *how* to implement multiple dispatch if needed), so don't do this lightly.

Comment: thanks, I thought of double dispatch, but didn't want to add methods to the classes since this is only used in one small area.

Answer (score 3):

You'll pay a cost in performance, but one simple way of accomplishing this is by using the dynamic run-time binder.  Simply cast the argument to `dynamic`:

```
foreach(A a in list) { DoSomething((dynamic)a); }
```

Comment: +1, forgot to mention i don't want to use dynamic, but this is a valid answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to use `dynamic` keyword, I guess something like

```
DoSomething((dynamic)a);
```

will do the job for you.

Otherwise, with static types, you could say

```
void DoSomething(A a)
{
  var aAsB = a as B;
  if (aAsB != null)
    DoSomething(aAsB);
  var aAsC = a as C;
  if (aAsC != null)
    DoSomething(aAsC);

  // general A case here
}
```

but that's maybe what you call a bunch of type checking.

Comment: +1, forgot to mention i don't want to use dynamic, but this is a valid answer. And ya, that's what I meant by type checking.